# Delete emails of shared mailbox using microsoft graph api

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, bearer-token, bad-request

```
import msal
from office365.graph_client import GraphClient
import json
import requests
import urllib3
authority_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/ae4df1f7-611e-444f-897e-f964e1205171'
authority=authority_url,
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
client_id = '------',
client_credential = '-----'
)
token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])
data = json.dumps(token)
dict1= json.loads(data)
token_value = dict1["access_token"]   ##Able to obtain the token
url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sharedmailbox@xyz.com/mailFolders/Inbox/messages/59f3b86064fc4590969f468bbffe323c@MW4PR15MB3453.namprd15.prod.outlook.com'
headers = {
    'authorization': "Bearer " + token_value,
    }
response = requests.delete(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

I am getting <Response [400]> please help!!!!!!!!!!!
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
Application permissions Mail.ReadWrite are given, still, it isn't working.
I am able to read data though, that is working fine.**

Answer (score 0):

From the line

```
url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sharedmailbox@xyz.com/mailFolders/Inbox/messages/59f3b86064fc4590969f468bbffe323c@MW4PR15MB3453.namprd15.prod.outlook.com
```

it looks like you trying to use the InternetMessageId to delete the Message which won't work, you need to find the underlying ItemId (which is the Exchange Mid). If all you have is the InternetMessageId then use a Filter first to find it eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sharedmailbox@xyz.com/mailFolders/Inbox/messages/$filter=internetMessageId eq '%3C59f3b86064fc4590969f468bbffe323c%40MW4PR15MB3453.namprd15.prod.outlook.com%3E'
```

InternetMessageId (those from Office365 anyway) always have enclosed in <> so you need to include and then escape that. You need to take the Base64 id property that is returned from you search then use that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, but i am getting a Response code 405 :

"code": "ErrorInvalidRequest",
        "message": "The OData request is not supported.",

Comment: Hey, I was able to delete now, using the {id} only. 
Though thanks for your help.